# ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Let me start with I'm a newb.
I'm following along the 'Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example' by Michael Hartl.
I'm at location 4503 in the ebook, chapter 7.

I'm trying to push my rails app to heroku and then view the corresponding web page. When I visit heroku web page all i see is error message "we're sorry but something went wrong".

```
chad@chad-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~/rails/sample_app$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 423, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (300/300), done.
Writing objects: 100% (423/423), 171.76 KiB, done.
Total 423 (delta 193), reused 239 (delta 91)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Installing rake (10.0.2)
   Installing i18n (0.6.1)
   Installing multi_json (1.4.0)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.8)
   Installing builder (3.0.4)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.8)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing rack (1.4.1)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing hike (1.2.1)
   Installing tilt (1.3.3)
   Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.8)
   Installing mime-types (1.19)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing treetop (1.4.12)
   Installing mail (2.4.4)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.8)
   Installing arel (3.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.8)
   Installing activeresource (3.2.8)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
   Installing execjs (1.4.0)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
   Installing json (1.7.5)
   Installing rdoc (3.12)
   Installing thor (0.16.0)
   Installing railties (3.2.8)
   Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Installing gravatar_image_tag (0.1.0)
   Installing jquery-rails (2.1.4)
   Installing pg (0.14.1)
   Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.2)
   Installing rails (3.2.8)
   Installing sass (3.2.3)
   Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
   Installing uglifier (1.3.0)
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Post-install message from rdoc:
   Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
   <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
   = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
   = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
   >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size: 8.9MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
       http://fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:fast-caverns-8821.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
chad@chad-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~/rails/sample_app$
```

$heroku logs

```
chad@chad-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~/rails/sample_app$ heroku logs    
2013-01-03T21:48:06+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by chadfaling@gmail.com
2013-01-03T21:48:06+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T21:48:35+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:48:36+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:48:36+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:49:17+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:49:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:49:20+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:49:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:49:23+00:00  heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:50:44+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:50:45+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:50:45+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:54:27+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=109.150.198.176 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T21:54:28+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=109.150.198.176 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T22:11:25+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes= 
2013-01-03T22:17:11+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation  started 
2013-01-03T22:17:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY resource by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:44+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:49+00:00 heroku[api]: Add  config by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:49+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 4c02e8a by chadfaling@gmail.com 
2013-01-03T22:17:51+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished 
2013-01-03T22:17:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server-p 18935` 
2013-01-03T22:17:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 53518` 
2013-01-03T22:17:57+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5) 
2013-01-03T22:17:57+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5) 
2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5) 
2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5) 
2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick 2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach 
2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL 
2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
2013-01-03T22:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:53518 2013-01-03T22:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:00] INFO  ruby1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux] 
2013-01-03T22:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 
2013-01-03T22:18:00+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=53518 
2013-01-03T22:18:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL 2013-01-03T22:18:02+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick 
2013-01-03T22:18:02+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach 
2013-01-03T22:18:02+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:18935 
2013-01-03T22:18:02+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server 
2013-01-03T22:18:03+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 
2013-01-03T22:18:03+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:03] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux] 
2013-01-03T22:18:03+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=18935 
2013-01-03T22:18:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 
2013-01-03T22:18:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up 
2013-01-03T22:18:04+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-03 22:18:04] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM 
2013-01-03T22:18:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select' 
2013-01-03T22:18:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL 
2013-01-03T22:18:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM 
2013-01-03T22:18:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 71.203.9.123 at 
2013-01-03 22:18:18 +0000 2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (7.6ms) 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2ms connect=3ms service=227ms status=500 bytes=643 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (13.6ms) 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled): 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!--[if it IE 9]> 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <!--[if it IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]--> 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3224471283117236114_42422900' 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %> 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb__1641714469046479695_41334620' 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <![endif]--> 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %> 
2013-01-03T22:18:18+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media=> 'print' %> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 71.203.9.123 at 
2013-01-03 22:27:21 +0000 2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms) 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.7ms) 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <!--[if it IE 9]> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled): 
 2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <![endif]--> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:  4: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts__stylesheets_html_erb__1641714469046479695_41334620' 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3224471283117236114_42422900' 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <!--[if it IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]--> 
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2013-01-03T22:27:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Can anyone help?
Please :)

Note:
I have read other post with similar issue and tried suggestions below:

1. in your config/environments/production.rb, you set

config.assets.precompile += %w( blueprint/screen.css blueprint/print.css )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `rake assets:precompile` and try again

Comment: chad@chad-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~/rails/sample_app/config/environments$ rake assets:precompile
(in /home/chad/rails/sample_app)
/home/chad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /home/chad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
chad@chad-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~/rails/sample_app/config/environments$ 

Now what? do i just do git push heroku ?

Comment: That should precompile your assets. In your /public directory you should now have an assets directory with files in. Push it to Heroku again and see if it works.

Comment: thanks Chris.
i do have files in the directory you mention. 
I did a git push heroku
i refreshed the webpage http://immense-headland-8649.herokuapp.com/
still see error message

Comment: 2013-01-03T21:35:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
2013-01-03T21:35:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled):

Comment: I've just found a post suggesting trying "heroku run rake assets:precompile" (running it on heroku obviously)

Comment: when i ran rake assests:precompile , the only file that was updated in /public/assets is

-rw-rw-r-- 1 chad chad    240 Jan  3 16:21 manifest.yml

Comment: I tried  "heroku run rake assets:precompile"

2013-01-03T21:45:58+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (blueprint/screen.css isn't precompiled):
2013-01-03T21:45:58+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <![endif]-->

Comment: i decided to try and make a new heroku app to push my project to
i did `$heroku create` `$git push heroku master` it made (http://fast-caverns-8821.herokuapp.com/) and i see the heroku welcome message when visiting link

Comment: my `$heroku logs` still show the old heroku app 2013-01-03T21:45:57+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ **host=immense-headland-8649.herokuapp.com** fwd=71.203.9.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=643

Comment: its as if im not pushing to the new app?

Comment: Thanks man, I just realized that... you are correct I had to update my git remote's url for heroku

Comment: thanks for all of the help above. Now that I've gotten better with rails I see your original answer was the correct solution, I had missed to include my custom.css file in pre-compile.